# How to use Linq on IList, to compare first value and second value present on the list based on some conditions.?

Tags: c#, linq, list

The issue I'm facing is, I want to check two conditions on Ilist values and I want to fetch the first value from the Ilist.

Eg: Ilist element contains the following values :

```
"[Name]","m","1","abcd"
```

and element1 conatins

```
"[Reset]","1.5".
```

I want to check whether the first element has square braces, and the second element is not "M" or "MD",

PFB the code which I had tried, but obviously key+1 doesn't work.

```
element.Cast<Object>().Where(key=>((Convert.ToString(key).StartsWith("[") 
 && Convert.ToString(key).EndsWith("]"))
 &&(!((Convert.ToString(key+1).Contains("MD")
 ||(Convert.ToString(key+1).Contains("M"))))))
```

Any pointers is highly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use indexers...element[0] & element[1]???

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you can iterate through the big list and then use the indexers as said.

```
 var rez= from p in BigList
          where p.Count() >1 && (p[0].StartsWith("[") && !p[1].Equals("M") && !p[1].Equals("MD"))
          select p;
```

This will return all the lists that have more than 2 elements and with your requirements

Comment: The List I'm working on is a List inside a list and hence has around 30 Ilist ..  thought to try linq, instead of for loops and if .

Comment: @ARJUNU that's a whole different story.

Comment: Thatz why I thought, I will have a quick question here in the forum.  Any pointers?

Comment: @ARJUNU recheck the answer (logic beat me for a minute on the earlier version).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve---i.e. take only the first items from the matching lists?

```
from x in new List<List<string>> { new List<string> { "[Name]", "m", "1", "abcd" }, new List<string> { "[Reset]","1.5" } }
where x.Count > 1 && Regex.IsMatch(x[0], @"^\[.*\]$") && !x[1].Equals("M", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !x[1].Equals("MD", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
select x[0]
```